# Does Modifying Data in Access Table Modify Data in an ODBC-connected Oracle SQL table?

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, odbc

I am new to access. I am using a tool/access database someone built, and it has an ODBC connection to an Oracle SQL database in it.

There are different queries on the side panel, and some of them are delete queries.

If I run these delete queries will they just modify data in my local access database without modifying the data in the Oracle Database?

Comment: Examine the delete queries.  Are they referring to access table or linked tables.

Comment: If the tables are linked the queries should affect the data in the `Oracle Db`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes these will change something in the database whether its linked with another access database table or oracle table and within the database.  To review the query you can open the queries in design view and run a normal select query so you can see what the queries are deleting. You can have a normal table image and or globe with a arrow in front pointing towards the table then its linked. A lot of times when I am testing I just run select queries and then I make a copy of what I will be deleting just in case anything goes wrong.